# cooling glass of milk glass and a jar of water

Tags: thermodynamics, water

When im given a steel glass of boiling milk which I cannot even touch, I used to put that glass in a jar surrounded with room-temp water and give it 10 mins. At the end, I used to find the steel glass is very mildly warm but the water itself is very hot. I never understood is water continuously absorbing heat from the milk glass even when the water itself gone warmer? I thought they should ideally be at the same temp at the end.

Comment: Your hand makes for a terrible thermometer. Have you tried measuring their *actual* temperatures?

Comment: To illustrate *why* touch is a very bad thermometer - have you ever noticed that while walking barefoot a tile floor feels much colder than a carpet when they're at the same temperature?

Comment: All depends on the heat transfer coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

As DavePhD has explained, the water would never be warmer than the metal. As you waited a long time, you can safely assume they are at the same temperature. But, why do they feel different?

Your hands are warm, and when touching a thermal insulator, such as wood, they will quickly transfer energy and heat up the surface of what you are touching, so it feels kind of warm. If you touch a thermal conductor, such as metal, it will still heat up the surface, but the metal will quickly dissipate that heat around so you are actually feeling a temperature closer to the real one.

Answer (score 0):

"I never understood is water continuously absorbing heat from the milk glass even when the water itself gone warmer? I thought they should ideally be at the same temp at the end.":

Yes, the water will continuously absorb heat until there is no temperature difference.  However, the rate of heat transfer will continously decrease.  The rate of heat transfer is proportional to the temperature difference.  This relationship is Newton's law of cooling.

"At the end, I used to find the steel glass is very mildly warm but the water itself is very hot":

The temperature of the metal will be approximately the average of the temperatures of the two liquids, at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

in the end whater and milk and all containers will be at the same temperature, it's just 10 mins wasn't enough.

the heat exchange is proportional to the temperature difference. so when milk is very hot the heat exchange from milk to water is fast, and it slows down as milk cools down and water heats up. they can meet somewhere in the middle at temp higher than room temp, then both slowly transfer heat to room, until room and all containers are at the same temp. btw, room heats up too, as you notice when cooking.